# automating adding comment to reddit when posting with praw

Tags: python, bots, reddit, praw

I'm creating a reddit bot. When I create a post that contains a image and a title. I want to automatically add a comment under that created post that contains a piece of text ("hello world").

I'm using python and praw.

I have looked at the documentation

https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/v3.6.0/pages/code_overview.html?highlight=comment#praw.objects.Submission.add_comment

But I couldnt manage to wrap my head around it and make it work.

This is the code I use to post a post with a title and a image.

```
reddit.subreddit(subreddit).submit_image(title, image_path)
```

How can I also add a comment to that created post?

Comment: Since `submit` doesn't seem to return the submitted post, you likely need to wait a short time (to allow for the post to go through) then get the latest post from the bots account and leave a comment on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the documentation for an old version of PRAW (3.6.0), which has not been updated since 2016 at least. The latest documentation can be found [here](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Based on your usage of `submit_image`, I guess you are using at least PRAW 6.1.0, since the method was [added in that version](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/v6.5.1/package_info/change_log.html#id8).

The methods [`submit`](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/subreddit.html#praw.models.Subreddit.submit), [`submit_image`](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/subreddit.html#praw.models.Subreddit.submit_image), and [`submit_video`](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/subreddit.html#praw.models.Subreddit.submit_video) all return the newly created [`Submission`](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/submission.html#praw.models.Submission). All you have to do then is [`reply`](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/submission.html#praw.models.Submission.reply) to the `Submission` like so:

```
my_post = reddit.subreddit(subreddit).submit_image(title, image_path)
my_post.reply("This is a comment.")
```

If you don't need to do anything with the post (and so don't need to store it in a variable), you could even do this in one line:

```
reddit.subreddit(subreddit).submit_image(title, image_path).reply("This is a comment.")
```